# Didn't find class "com.jambod.user.model.ProcessModel" on path: DexPathList error just in release apk

Tags: android, kotlin, release, android-multidex

I write an application and I use `dagger-android` and navigation component on it.For reduce size of `apk` I enable `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources`. But When i generate apk and open app, the app is crashed.I traced the logcat and the error was `Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
Didn't find class "com.jambod.user.model.ProcessModel" on path: DexPathList`. This is code of `ProcessModel`:

```
    data class ProcessModel(
    var id: String,
    var state: String ,
    var originLat: Double,
    var originLon: Double,
    var originAddress: String,
    var city: String ,
    var client: User ,
    var broker: Broker,
    var handover: HandOver ,
    var startTime: Long ,
    var endTime: Long ,
    var clientScore: Int,
    var role:String,
    var isFirstFinishedProcess:Boolean

) : Serializable {
}
```

And This is my Application class:

```
    class MyApplication : DaggerApplication() {

    val TAG="MyApplication"
    @Inject
    lateinit var mapboxMap: CedarMaps

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {

        Log.e(TAG,"applicationInjector")
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()

    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.e(TAG,"onCreate")
        setMapview()
    }

    override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base)
        Log.e(TAG,"attachBaseContext")
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }

    private fun setMapview() {
        mapboxMap.setClientID("jambod-3804728105994932624")
                .setClientSecret("b37qDGphbWJvZLqxi8hCuQhrjCXtqKs9V536SyiAAHQP01FzTg3G0iat")
                .setContext(this)
    }

}
```

And this part of code mobile-navigation file that in the logcat has error:

```
  <fragment android:id="@+id/detailProcessFragment" android:name="com.jambod.user.ui.DetailProcessFragment"
          android:label="fragment_detail_process" tools:layout="@layout/fragment_detail_process">
    <argument android:name="KEY_PROCESS"
        app:argType="com.jambod.user.model.ProcessModel"
        app:nullable="true"
        android:defaultValue="@null"/>
</fragment>
```

According the [document](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#keep) I create a `multidex-config.txt` file and add it on `build.gradle` But the problem did not solve.This is `build.gradle` file:

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.jambod.user"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `"minifyEnabled true"` and proguard. **"minifyEnabled true"** will some time remove the model classes that you have used in your app. Add below line in **Gradle scripts -> proguard-rules.pro** file. Below line will keep the class and its members to your final APK.

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames  class  com.jambod.user.model.ProcessModel.** { *; }
```

Comment: https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/master/compatibility-faq.md